Regex in python to split sentences by full stop (dot / period character) but ignore abbreviations and dates which contain full stop?
I want to search for a keyword in the text and to extract each sentence which contains the keyword. When extracting each sentence, I want to ignore full stops (meaning periods or dot characters) in dates and in some abbreviations ('st.' and 'numb.')
Example:
keyword = grand
text: "The boy will visit his grandmother tomorrow, on 01.02.2024, who lives on Downing St. 10. The following day he will go to school. The day after, on 03.02.2014, he will visit his grandfather."

I expect the two sentences which contain the keyword 'grand', where the fullstops in dates and the shortening 'st' are ignored:
["The boy will visit his grandmother tomorrow, on 01.02.2024, who lives on Downing St. 10.", "The day after, on 03.02.2014, he will visit his grandfather." ]

Current Regex:
out = re.findall('[.](([a-zяA-Z ,:;-])|((([0-9]{1,2}[./]){0,1}([0-9]{1,2}[./]){0,1}([0-9]{2,4}))))*'+keyword+'\w+\W+([a-zA-Z ,:;-]|(([0-9]{1,2}[./]){0,1}([0-9]{1,2}[./]){0,1}([0-9]{2,4})))*(?<!((st)|(numb)))[.]', x)

I want the regex to: start with full stop, look for letters, punctuations or dates before the keyword, find the keyword, followed by letters, punctuation or dates, until a full stop which is not preceded by 'st' or a numeral character (0-9).
Result: error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern


Yes, Python regex does not do variable length lookbehinds.  The easiest choice is to not use a look behind but scan the 'ST" or " NUMB" as part of the string and use a capturing group to isolate the part you want.

I suggest to replace fullstops those you don't wanna match first.
for example:
import re
sentence = ". The boy will visit his grandmother tomorrow on 01.02.2024 who lives on Downing st. 10. The following day he will go to school. The day after on 03.02.2014 he will visit his grandfather"
keyword = 'grand'

# replace fullstops in `st.` and `date.month` with `*dot*`
new_sentence = re.sub(r'((?<=st)(?<!\d{2}\.\d{2})\.)|((?<=\d{2})\.(?=\d{2}))', '*dot*', sentence)

result = [re.sub(r'\*dot\*','.', s) for s in re.findall(r'\s*([^\.]+%s[^\.]+\.?)' % keyword, new_sentence)]
print(result)
# [
#   'The boy will visit his grandmother tomorrow on 01.02.2024 who lives on Downing st. 10.',  
#   'The day after on 03.02.2014 he will visit his grandfather'
# ]

